# What is the difference between jquery.size() and jquery.length?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between jquery.size() and jquery.length?
like:

```
$('#test').size();
$('#test').length;
```

Comment: .size() and .length() both returns the number of element in an object. But length is faster than the size because length is a property and size is a method.

Comment: Simply asking the search engine of your choice would have given you the answer instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery .size() method returns number of element in the object. 
But it is not preferred to use the size() method as jQuery provide .length property and which does the same thing. 
But the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 2):

> The **`.size()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8**. Use the `.length` property instead.
>
> The `.size()` method is **functionally equivalent** to the `.length` property; however, the **`.length` property is preferred** because it does not have the overhead of a function call.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 1):

The `.size()` method returns number of element in the object. But it is preferred to use `.length` property which does the same thing but it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Ref : http://tonyfreed.com/blog/top_jquery_interview_question_2015

Comment: If you cut and paste an exact answer shouldn't you credit the source: http://tonyfreed.com/blog/top_jquery_interview_question_2015 or http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Reference  added

Answer (score 0):

It returns the same value.
But size() is deprecated since jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 0):

No, both are same. size() actually returns length. So use directly length to avoid extra method call.

Answer (score 0):

Both length property and size() are same. But length property is preferred as a much effective way.

Refer https://api.jquery.com/size/